# Show that there are no primitive roots in $\left(\Bbb{Z}/2^k \right)$ if $k>2$

Tags: number-theory

I need to show that

there are no primitive roots in $\left(\Bbb{Z}/2^k \right)$ if $k>2$

How should I go about this question? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove by induction on $k$ that $g^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$ for all odd $g$ and $k>2$.

This will suffice because a primitive root mod $2^k$ would have to be an odd number $g$ such that $n=2^{k-1}=\phi(2^k)$ is the smallest $n$ such that $g^n \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$.

Comment: How is this a hint?

Comment: i don't know how your hint would help.

Comment: @Ashley, see my edited answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this, but I'm a bit confused. If $n=2^{k-1}=\phi(2^k)$ and $n$ is the smallest such that $g^n \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$, then how can $g^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$?

$2^{k-2}$ is smaller than $2^{k-1}$.

Comment: @chris, we want to prove that there are *no* primitive roots mod $2^k$. The hint proves that the smallest $n$ such that $g^n \equiv 1$ is at most $2^{k-2}$ and so can never be $2^{k-1}$.

Comment: Right thanks, I forgot we were trying to prove there was no roots. To prove $g^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$ would you right $a2^k+bg^{2^{k-2}}=1$ and solve that using division algorithm, or is there a better way to prove that?

Comment: I tried induction on $k$ and ran into trouble pretty much immediately. Using $k=1$ as a base case, I got $g^{2^{-1}}=\sqrt{g}$ so I would need to show $\sqrt{g} \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. I'm not sure how to go about that so I tried starting with $k=2$ and got $g^{2^{0}}=g$ and I would need to show that $g \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ but that fails to be true what $g=3$. Since we are trying to prove this for $k>2$ should I have started induction with $k=3$?

Comment: @lhf so the base case $k=3$ is easy. I think I have the idea for the induction step, but I would appreciate feedback. Suppose $g^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$ then $(g^{2^{k}})=(g^{2^{k}})^-4$. $g^{2^{(k+1)-2}}=g^{2^{k-1}}=(g^{2^{k}})^-2$. Since $(g^{2^{k}})^-4=((g^{2^{k}})^-2)^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$, $(g^{2^{k}})^-2 \equiv 1 \mod 2^k$ and so $(g^{2^{k}})^-2 \equiv 1 \mod 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: @chris, this is getting too long for comments. I suggest that you ask a separate question so that we can clear these comments.